# How to use NativeBase Header component with react-native-router-flux?

Tags: react-native, drawer, react-native-router-flux, native-base

I tried to use drawer on my project where I use **NativeBase** and **react-native-router** in it. Everything works except that the button inside header is not functional(I can't tap this certain button). This issue only happen if I wrap my Main Page inside `<Scene key="draw">`, here is my code:

**App.js**

```
<Scene key="draw" component={SideMenu} open={false} hideNavBar={true}>
  <Scene key='main' component={Home} hideNavBar={true}/>
</Scene>
```

**Header on main**

```
<Left>
 <Button transparent onPress={()=>Alert.alert("burger tapped")}>
  <Icon name='menu' />
 </Button>
</Left>
```

My purpose is when I tap the button, it will open the drawer but the button is not functional at all when I do the code like above example. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The common workaround is to put header component from nativebase into each container component(screen). This approach even implemented into their [boilerplate for the Ignite.](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/ignite-native-base-boilerplate/blob/master/boilerplate/App/Containers/CardExample.js#L12)

The other way is to to push custom NavBar as a prop to the scene component. Modify the [built-in NavBar](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/src/NavBar.js) to use nativebase components instead of the default:

```
import CustomNavBar from './CustomNavBar';
import Main from './Components/Main';

<Router>
  <Scene
   component={Main}
   key="main"
   type={ActionConst.RESET}
   navBar={CustomNavBar}
  />
</Router>
```

Good luck!

Comment: I already tried that but navBar from react-native-router won't show if it's wrapped with <Scene key="draw">

Comment: Have you tried to pass navBar prop to the Royter component?

Comment: I haven't tried that, can you give a sample code on how can I do that?

Comment: <Router navBar={CustomNavBar}>

Comment: Appeared that child components doesn't recieve navBar prop from the parent, so it won't work for the nested scenes. Specify navBar explicitly for the each scene.

Comment: I can't understand "Specify navBar explicitly for the each scene.", can you explain more or give me example code?

Comment: `<Scene
   component={Component}
   key="someKey"
   navBar={CustomNavBar}
  />`

Comment: I've tried that too, it didn't work for me. CustomNavBar never shows.

Comment: Is there a way to pass argument to CustomNavBar using `navBar={CustomNavBar}` approach?

Answer (score 0):

NativeBase showcases this with its [NativeBase-KitchenSink](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink)

This should answer your question